# Structuring list of list of strings into list of lists of lists of strings in python

Tags: python, list

I have data that looks like this:

```
original_data = 
[['not',
  'ahead',
  'um let me think',
  'thats not very encouraging if they had a cast of thousands on the other end'],
  ['okay civil liberties tell me your position',
 'probably would go ahead'],
 ['oh',
 'it up so i dont know where you really go',
 'well most of my problem with this latest task',
 'its some i kind of dont want to put in the time to do it',
 'right so im saying ive got a lot of other things to do']]
```

However, I am doing some preprocessing before modeling its structure needs to look like this:

```
new_data = 
[[['not'],
  ['ahead'],
  ['um let me think'],
  ['thats not very encouraging if they had a cast of thousands on the other end']],
  [['okay civil liberties tell me your position'],
 ['probably would go ahead']],
 [['oh'],
 ['it up so i dont know where you really go'],
 ['well most of my problem with this latest task'],
 ['its some i kind of dont want to put in the time to do it'],
 ['right so im saying ive got a lot of other things to do']]]
```

How can I go about doing this? Thanks.

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: `new_list = map(list, another_list)` will wrap each element of `another_list` in a list.

Comment: I see no evidence of any attempt or research here?

Answer (score 2):

Just try to do

```
new_data = [[[j] for j in i] for i in original_data]
```

> The **[j]** is wrapping the words into a list
>
> And the rest is only to loop through the list

Answer (score 0):

This list concatenation will return what you want:

```
new_data = [[[l] for l in lst] for lst in original_data]
```

Output:

```
[[['not'], ['ahead'], ['um let me think'], ['thats not very encouraging if they had a cast of thousands on the other end']], [['okay civil liberties tell me your position'], ['probably would go ahead']], [['oh'], ['it up so i dont know where you really go'], ['well most of my problem with this latest task'], ['its some i kind of dont want to put in the time to do it'], ['right so im saying ive got a lot of other things to do']]]
```